# How to properly convert an array of objects to CSV with papaparse?

Tags: node.js, csv, papaparse

I'm performing a mongdb database query which downloads an array of objects and then I want to convert it to CSV. I'm using `babyparse` which is papaparse alternative version for node.

This is what I'm trying:

```
    Player.find({}).
      exec(function(err, players) {
        console.log(players.length);
        var csv = papaparse.unparse(players, {
          quotes: false,
          delimiter: ',',
          newline: '\n'
        });

        response.set({'Content-Type': 'application/force-download',
                      'Content-disposition':'attachment; filename=players.csv'});


        response.send(200, csv);
      });
  }
```

However this won't offer a correct CSV file but something weird, like a merge of csv content with java script functions content.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the JSON Data using following function

```
JSON.flatten = function(data) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
            for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 if(cur[i].constructor === Object)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
                 else
                 {

                   if(cur.length > 1)
                    {
                        result[prop] = (result[prop] || "") + cur[i] + ";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[prop] = cur;
                    }

                 }

            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}
```

Modify as per your case :)